# Warning: substitutefont no longer working!

Tags: fonts

This is not a question, but just a warning to others — but please correct me if I'm wrong about this:

As of today's TeXLive 2023 updates (2023-08-16 but possibly a few days before), with

```
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
```

there is no longer a package `substitutefont.sty` and the `\substitutefont` command therefore no longer works with (pdf)LaTeX.

That came as a total surprise to me.

(The issue does not arise with Unicode TeX engines, of course, where `\newfontfamily` is used instead.)

The following source shows both:

- the old, now non-working, `substitutefont` package loading and command invocation (commented out in my source); and
- use instead of the `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution` command from the LaTeX (2020-02 release or later) programming layer.

The source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage{substitutefont} % now obsolete!
\usepackage[russian,ngerman,polish,english]{babel}
\babeltags{russian=russian,french=french,german=ngerman,polish=polish}
%\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF} % for Cyrillic - old way
\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF} % for Cyrillic - new way
\usepackage{newtx}

\begin{document}

The Cyrillic name \textrussian{Александров} is transliterated into English as Alexsandrov.

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: new way to do font substitution]

The `substitutefont` package, version 0.1.5 2023-08-13, is still on CTAN, but in https://ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/substitutefont.

The package's README.md file includes this information:

```
. admonition:: This package is obsolete.
   
   Authors are encouraged to use the command
   ``\DeclareFontfamilySubstitution`` provided by the LaTeX kernel.

   Existing documents can be updated by removing
   ``\usepackage{substitutefont}`` and replacing all uses of
   ``\substitutefont`` with ``\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution``.
```

Comment: I don't know why the package has been withdrawn. This invalidates several old documents for no reason. Complain with the author.

Comment: \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution is not a L3 layer command but yes, the author declared the package obsolete, there was a message on c.t.t. about it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: what is "c.t.t."?

Comment: comp.text.tex, ctan sents announcement there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I stand corrected, having misread the package author's README comment "The package is obsoleted by the NFSS command ``\DeclareFontfamilySubstitution`` added to the  LaTeX kernel in the 2020-02 release [ltnews31]_."

Comment: Seems like wider distribution of the info beyond comp.text.tex may be needed.

Comment: @murray they are also here: https://ctan.org/ctan-ann and here https://lists.dante.de/pipermail/ctan-ann/, https://lists.dante.de/pipermail/ctan-ann/2023-August/036011.html